# MFMessageComposeViewController shows blank white screen in iOS7

Tags: iphone, xcode, sms, ios7

there's a problem when I try to send a large recipients list (e.g more than 40) using MFMessageComposeViewController. In iOS7, it will show a blank white screen for 20s or more before displaying the SMS compose view. This does not occur for iOS5 and iOS6.

Below is the existing code that I'm using,

```
NSArray * recipients;

for (NSIndexPath * index in selectedRows) 
{ 
   NSDictionary *dictionary = [data objectAtIndex:index.row];
   NSString *phoneNum =  [dictionary objectForKey:@"contactNum"];
   recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:phoneNum, nil]];
}

MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    controller.body = bodyOfMessage;
    controller.recipients = recipients;
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self ;
    controller.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    [(id)_delegate presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Below are the output message that I received when I try to send to many.

```
timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.mobilesms.compose
Received memory warning.
Received memory warning.
Received memory warning.
Received memory warning.
Received memory warning.
Received memory warning.
Received memory warning.
Received memory warning.
Received memory warning.
```

Comment: I have the same issue.
I've opened a bug report in bugreport.apple.com with id #14994563
after two days an Apple Engineering ask me for a console log, i've attached it, but, for now nothing happened. I've wrote many thread in apple developer forum without find any solution ... today i wrote to tim cook ..

Comment: It's a weird bug. Out of 4 iPhone5 devices that I have tested, 2 experienced this problem while the other 2 display the SMS compose view immediately. I'm puzzled.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my shipped app. Seems OK below 30 or so contacts, but gets progressively longer delay above that. 86 didnt return at all! Best guess is this relates to the way that contacts are now coloured according to the method that will be used to send them. On iPad you now get a bunch of spinners appearing against each contact as it works out whether they are known to iMessage. I'm not sure if this was a late addition to iOS7, but I didn't spot this stuff here in the betas.

Comment: LDWP- are you saying the same code consistently worked with the same size group on some devices and not others?

One user reported different results according to whether MMS was enabled, could that be the difference between devices?

Comment: Peter Johnson - I have tested and it's working on devices running beta iOS7. Devices that were upgraded to the latest iOS7 from iTunes have this problem. I have also tested by toggling the MSS enabled settings but problem still exists.

Comment: There's a big thread on Apple forums about this. This is an iOS 7 bug introduced after the GM build and is still there in iOS 7.0.2. Apple is however aware of this and looking into fixing it.

Comment: The problem has been resolved in iOS 7.0.3.

Comment: Still getting this error in iOS 12.0.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem where I got the message in the console "

> timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.mobilesms.compose

The problem was that I tried in my app to add the number as a string, but because of the localization request, I have put it in a form:`NSArray *recipents = @[NSLocalizedString(@"numberForRegistrationViaSms", @"")];`

and

```
[messageController setRecipients:@[recipents]];
```

That didn't work for some reason but, when I put just simply, `[messageController setRecipients:@[@"123456789"]];`, the SMS composer appears without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

I to had the same problem then figured

`controller.recipients` = // should always be an array of strings.

Make sure the phone numbers you send to controller.recipients are NSString.

Answer (score 1):

I think I maybe resolve this:

**//must initiate new NSString object**

```
NSString *phoneStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",... ];                                                     

MFMessageComposeViewController *aCtrl = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
aCtrl.recipients                      = @[phoneStr];
...

Then OK.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.

> - timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.mobilesms.compose
> - Message Cancelled

Instead of this:

```
    NSString *phoneNumber = @"888888888";
    [picker setRecipients:@[phoneNumber]];
```

Try this:

```
    NSString *phoneNumber = person.phoneNumber;
    [picker setRecipients:@[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", phoneNumber]]];
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

The problem has been resolved in iOS 7.0.3.

Comment: Just had <CKSMSComposeRemoteViewController: 0x16e08050> timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.mobilesms.compose appear on 7.0.4

Comment: Also get this on 8.1.1. Yay apple!

Comment: Problem is also in 8.0.2 version

Comment: Problem also exists in iOS 8.3 .